# Copy Vector3 position from one Camera View to another

Tags: c#, math, matrix, camera, monogame

In Monogame (same as XNA in this question)
I need to copy objects (3D models) from one place in the world to another.
The problem is that i can't just throw them in one pile with the same position, i want to paste them into the world, with the exact same setup (distance and rotation) relatively to the Camera from where i copied them.

I haven't really got any luck with copy-paste more than one object. If i copy one object, its easy because i can just insert it in front of the camera (View matrix), but when there is a lot of objects with specific setups, i really can't manage to paste them into the scene with the same setup relatively to the camera.

```cs
// I have code that clones my 3D objects when pressing CTRL+C
List<3DObject> copiedObjects = new List<3DObject>();
foreach(var obj in SelectedObjects){
    copiedObjects.Add(obj.DeepClone());
}

// i then have this code, when pasting in the objects (CTRL+V)
// calculate new position and rotation of pasted objects
// but it doesnt work as expected. And i cant figure out why.
foreach (var newObj in newObjects)
{
    if (newObj.ObjectLink == null)
    {
      #region NEW

      // newObj is a clone of another object in space A.
      // now, its pasted into space B (a different location with the camera (location and rotation)
      // this only works on objects that aren't rotated, and moved.
      // so it basically sucks.

      float pitch_delta = scene.Camera.Pitch - _copy_camera_pitch;
      float yaw_delta = scene.Camera.Yaw - _copy_camera_yaw;

      Vector3 camera_delta = _copy_camera_position - scene.Camera.Position;
      Vector3 newpos = newObj.Position - camera_delta;

      newObj.Position = Vector3.Transform(
        newpos, 
        Matrix.CreateTranslation(-scene.Camera.Position) 
        * scene.Camera.RotationMatrix 
        * Matrix.CreateTranslation(scene.Camera.Position) 
        * Matrix.Invert(newObj.TransformRotation));

      newObj.Rotation += new Vector3(MathHelper.ToDegrees(pitch_delta), MathHelper.ToDegrees(yaw_delta), 0);

      #endregion
    }
}
```

In order to make this work, i need to allow the user to be at one place in the world, and select 1 or more objects and then press CTRL+C.

Then the user can "fly" to a different place in the world, and press CTRL+V.
The objects should now be placed in the world, at the same spot as they were copied from (relatively to the camera)

Comment: I think the missing bit of information you need in the code above is "how far" the user has traveled since they pressed CTRL+C. If you where to store a `SelectedPosition` at copy time, then it should be easy enough to calculate the *offset* when positioning the pasted objects.

Comment: Hmm. That information is simple for me to get. I need the distance and direction relative to the camera, so that when the user presses CTRL+P, the object(s) are pasted into the view exactly as when they were copied, just in a different location. Thanks for your suggestion anyway :)